# Starlette - Type Error: FormData object is not callable

Tags: python, reactjs, post, audio, starlette

I'm uploading an audio file to a Starlette server and I'm trying to access it the way they recommend in the [docs](https://www.starlette.io/requests/), but it's giving me a not callable error. I gather the issue is calling `.form()` on the `request` object, but I'm not sure how else to read it in.

Server Route:

```py
@app.route('/api/upload_track/', methods=['POST'])
async def separate_vocals(request):
    audio_data = await request.form()
    separator = Separator('spleeter:2stems')
    audio_bytes = await (audio_data['file'].read())
    return audio_data
```

Client:

```js
function FileUploadSingle() {
  const [file, setFile] = useState([]);

  const handleFileChange = (e) => {
    if (e.target.files) {
      setFile(e.target.files[0]);
    }
  };
   
    let audioData = new FormData();

    const blob = new Blob([file], {type: 'audio/mpeg'});
    audioData.append('file', file, 'file');
    console.log(file);
    console.log(audioData.get('file'));
    //  Uploading the file using the fetch API to the server
    fetch(`${RESTAPI_URL}/api/upload_track/`, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: audioData, 
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => console.log(data))
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));
  };

}

export default FileUploadSingle;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following error:

```
TypeError: 'FormData' object is not callable
```

is caused when returning the `FormData` object you obtained, by using `await request.form()`, from your endpoint (i.e., `return audio_data`)—which I am sure it is not the one you would like to return in the first place, but rather the `audio_bytes`. Now, if you attempted to return the byte array using `return audio_bytes`, you would get:

```
TypeError: 'bytes' object is not callable
```

In Starlette, you could use the [`Response`](https://www.starlette.io/responses/#response) class to return `bytes`, for example:

```py
from starlette.responses import Response

@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
async def upload(request):
    form = await request.form()
    contents = await form['file'].read()
    return Response(contents)
```

The `Response` class also allows you to specify the [MIME type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types) (also known as media type), using the `media_type` parameter.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked! Yeah need to do some processing on it with the spleeter library but just needed to see whether it was sending correctly (and not overly familiar with Python)